# passing reference of boost::shared_ptr of inherited type to a function

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, shared-ptr, factory

I'm having the following code:

```
struct A : boost::noncopyable {
  virtual A& copy (const A&);
};
struct B : A {
  virtual B& copy (const B&);
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr <A> APtr; 
typedef boost::shared_ptr <B> BPtr; 
typedef std::string Key;

struct AFactory {
static APtr s_get (const Key& key) {
APtr a;
//... //some factory code
return a;     
}
};
```

Here is the old implementation of class C, and the usage

```
class COld {
public:
  void get (APtr a) {
    a->copy (*_a) ;
  }
private:
  Key _key;  
  APtr _a;
};

int main (void) {
 APtr a = AFactory::s_get ("b"));
 BPtr b = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast <B> (AFactory::s_get ("b"));
 COld c;

 c.get (a); //works good
 c.get (b); //works good

 return 1;
}
```

I'm trying to be more friendly to users, and allocate the passed object if it is NULL

```
class CNew {
public:
  void get (APtr& a) {
    if (!a) {
      a = AFactory::s_get (_key);
    }
    a->copy (*_a) ;
  }
private:
  Key _key;  
  APtr _a;
};

int main (void) {
 //current usage
 APtr a;
 BPtr b;
 APtr ap = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast <A> (b);

 CNew c;

 c.get (a);
 c.get (b); // here I get the error: 
 c.get (ap); // ok, but i don't like it

 return 1;
}
```

error: a reference of type "APtr &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "BPtr"

sure users can cast BPtr to APtr to pass to c.get ():

```
APtr ap = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast <A> (b);
c.get (ap);
```

but that's not a very elegant

I don't want to share pointers from C::_a, just copy the data
How can I make the new implementation of C::get () working and convenient?

Comment: It is helpful if your example code is at least syntactically correct. In this case, you should be able to provide us with a minimal example that compiles and demonstrates the problem, no?

Comment: @Rook I fixed the code, but you may understand the problem without compilation

Comment: The code isn't fixed... the definition of `AFactory` is totally broken, `s_get` is private, you've used `Class` instead of `class`, etc.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect: the same thing would happen with references to pointers, i.e. you can't pass `B*` to a function taking `A*&`. And there are still a lot of problems with the code (e.g. missing semicolons, `Class` miscapitalized, etc.).

Comment: You can't pass a `B*` to a function expecting `A*&` either, and for the same reason: you'd end up with a pointer to `B` containing what was actually a pointer to `A`.

Comment: What you're trying to do is forbidden because it would break the type system. Why are you trying to do it? What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @Alan Stokes I'm trying to write a function that returns a reference to a shared pointer of object of base type.

Comment: You can just return a shared pointer, returning a reference to one is a bad idea. And you can construct a `shared_ptr<A>` from a `B*`; it is safe and legal. The other way round, which is what you seem to be trying, is neither.

Comment: @Alan Stokes, what if I change the content of "px" member of "a"? if I pass by value, "px" will remain unchanged!!

Comment: You are trying to make a B pointer to point to an A object. Why do you expect this to work?

Comment: Inheritance works the other way around. If B inherits A, you can make an A pointer point to a B object.

Comment: @n.m. so why if I remove the reference in the function definition, "c.get (b)" compiles without any problem? (see some of answers here)

Comment: "you need to read OOP basics". Will gladly do, doubt it will work on me because I write OOP C++ code for a living for the last 20 years or so, so my brains are quite a bit rusty. But please nevertheless don't hesitate to suggest reading material for me. I am currently re-reading "Agile software development" by R. C. Martin, that covers a range of advanced OOP topics among other things. I recommend it. But let me ask you a question. Out of two statements, `A* a = new B;` and `B* b = new A;` which one is supposed to work and which one is not, and why?

Comment: I am trying to help users here, you can check my history on this site if you doubt it. I will continue in the chat if you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53905/discussion-between-n-m-and-hellfire769)

Comment: Those who put the question on hold, I've edited my question. Can you please give a feedback on what should be clarified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets look at the offending function.

```
void get (APtr& a) {
  if (!a) {
    a = AFactory::s_get (_key);
  }
  a->copy (*_a) ;
}
```

It takes a smart pointer reference, possibly points it at an instance of the smart pointer's resource and then copies some values into it.

The problem is that an `APtr&` cannot reference an instance of `BPtr`. This shouldn't really be that surprising... if you could pass in a `BPtr` masquerading as an `APtr` and then assign a new `A` to it, you've violated the type system. Consider that on return from `c.get(b)`, you could invoke `b->some_method_A_does_not_have()`... if `b` was somehow holding an instance of `A`, you'd end up triggering some sort of runtime error. You wouldn't expect a `B*` to hold a pointer to an `A`, after all.

The easiest solution is to pass in `a` by value, and demand that it be initialised so you don't have to replace its managed resource.

```
void get (APtr a) {
  if (!a)
    throw std::exception();

  a->copy (*_a) ;
}
```

This is not perhaps quite so convenient for the consumers of your library, but the required boilerplate is minimal and the behaviour is easy to describe. The overhead of passing a copy of the `shared_ptr` is small, and should not be a problem unless `get` is heavily used. If it is heavily used, demanding your users take extra steps in the name of efficiency is justifiable.

Another possibility is to template both your factory class and `get` method.

```
template <class T>
struct Factory
{
  static boost::shared_ptr<T> s_get()
  {
    boost::shared_ptr <T> t;
    // whatever
    return t;
  }
};

class C
{
public:
  template <class T>
  void get(boost::shared_ptr<T>& t) {
    if (!t) {
      t = Factory<T>::s_get();
    }
    dynamic_cast<A*>(t.get())->copy(*_a);
  }

  // etc
```

Comment: Object Slicing??? I don't see how Object Slicing is relevant, we are not dealing with construction or assignment in polymorphic inheritance.

Comment: The first option won't work since "a" may replace its referred object. The second option is not applicable, since I don't want to return the shared pointer of "c::_a", (this will share the reference count) For instance if a::px = 0 (the pointer in the boost::shared_ptr) when a is passed, and we want to allocate it in get

Comment: @hellfire769 so... what exactly is `getParams` intended to do? Is it intended to pass out _a via a smart pointer (so modifications to `b` affect `_a`), or is it merely intended to copy some values from `_a` into `b`, but leave both objects as entirely separate?

Comment: @ Rook  exactly the second.

Comment: @ Rook :-) The second option is great, but why are you using dynamic_cast with get(), instead of boost::dynamic_pointer_cast? anyway its great using templates. But I'm a bit restricted for now to dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: As to the first option, this is my current code, which I'm trying to extend

Comment: @hellfire769 re: `dynamic_pointer_cast`: it creates a new `shared_ptr` instance and modifies the refcount of the managed resource. This seems to be the sort of thing you're trying to avoid.

Comment: btw, we do get object slicing here, so we need to change for copy

Comment: I edited my post to avoid it

Comment: in the templated answer, you omitted the "C"'s class data members. If I add them, I get an error: "identifier "T" is undefined
      boost::shared_ptr<T> _a;" Can you give a full definition of C that compiles?